# Linear model with AR hidden state

Tags: time-series, references, autoregressive, latent-variable, state-space-models

Suppose everyday I want to predict the temperature reading taken somewhere in a city. I have some explanatory variables, say humidity and wind speed. And I have data for $K$ cities. So the data look like

```
date       city   humidity    wind    temperature
2000-09-01 London 70          12      15.0
2000-09-01 London 50          6       15.3
2000-09-01 London 80          7       15.5
2000-09-01 Paris  60          4       16.0
2000-09-02 London 80          1       18.0
2000-09-02 London 81          2       18.2
2000-09-02 Paris  60          4       16.0
```

Number of readings per day is random. Suppose $K = 250$ and some cities have 900+ rows and some cities have only 30 rows.

The model I want to build is to have a hidden "normalised" temperature of each day for each city which follows an AR process

$$\tilde{T}_d^{city} = \alpha\tilde{T}_{d-1}^{city} + \epsilon,$$

and the observed temperature is

$$T_d^{city} = \mu+X\beta+\tilde{T}_d^{city}+\eta,$$

where $X$ are my explanatory variables, $\mu, \alpha<1, \beta$ are to be fitted and are independent of day or city. $\epsilon,\eta$ are iid Normal (and I'm not sure if I should include $\eta$ here).

Is there any literature on such model or similar ones? How can I fit this model?

NB

1. The temperature example is for illustration only. I know it's wrong to have a constant $\alpha<1$ for the whole year, but let's just say my period goes from summer to winter.
2. This is not a regression with AR error but similar. Regression-AR deals with one long time series while I have 250 time series with different lengths.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what relation there is across the different cities. Do you impose some common parameters across them? Otherwise you would be considering univariate time series (from the technical point of view). Also, if there is a relation between the cities, then probably a *dynamic factor model* could be a relevant keyword. Unfortunately, you might have some added trouble due to the number of observations being different across cities, but an EM-style algorithm could cope with that.

Comment: You never responded to the comment. Are you still interested in this question?